# RxAndroid aborts or does not build when Play Services is added

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, rx-java, rx-android, retrolambda

I'm having some issues getting RxAndroid and Google Play Services running together or even build the project in Android Studio after adding Google Play Services.  I've used the following 2 helpful sites as references: [How to setup retrolambda](https://frenchstone.wordpress.com/2015/07/25/how-to-setup-the-retrolambda-to-android-studio-project/) and [Functional Reactive Programming with RxJava in Android](https://ykode.github.io/2015/02/20/android-frp-rxjava-retrolambda.html).  Now maybe I missed something, but I've had issues with java.exe (java 8) either aborting during the build with an exit error or issues with java 8 when running the actual application. From the errors I deduced that I needed retrolambda and there were still issues building my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, research, etc. Here's what I found that worked for me.  Please note that some of the commented out values at the end of a line were values that I had tried previously.

**Project build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
//        jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'   //1.3.0
    classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.0'   //2.5.0
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
//        jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
```

**Module build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22   //21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"    //21.1.2

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.app"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22  //21
    multiDexEnabled = true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    preDexLibraries = true  //false
    incremental false
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'  //21.0.3   22.2.1
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' //7.8.0
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
}

retrolambda {
jvmArgs '-noverify'
jdk System.getenv("JAVA8_HOME")
oldJdk System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME")
javaVersion JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
defaultMethods false
incremental true

}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*
```

In addition, I added the above referenced path environment values JAVA7_HOME, JAVA8_HOME which point to the appropriate directory for each java install.